# How to know if an overriden method calls its super method or not?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Consider this situation, where a Player class inherits from a more general Actor class:

### Actor.gd

```
class_name Actor extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    print("I am an actor")
    _foo()
        
func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was an actor")
```

### Player.gd

```
class_name Player extends Actor


func _ready():
    print("I am a player")

func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was a player")
```

---

When one instantiate a player in a scene, we have this output:

```
I am an actor
I was thinking I was a player
I am a player
```

How to know when a method will call its super class?

Comment: Could you try this with another function? Something other than _init and _ready?

Comment: @Vaillancourt this is what I have tried with `_foo()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### On the mechanism of Ready

The underlying mechanism for Godot calling `_ready` are [notifications](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/best_practices/godot_notifications.html).

What a script observes is the following:

- Godot calls `_notification` with `NOTIFICATION_POST_ENTER_TREE` (27).
- Godot initializes any onready variables.
- Godot calls `_ready`.
- Godot calls `_notification` with `NOTIFICATION_READY` (13).
- Godot emits the ready signal.

The mechanism is in `Node::_propagate_ready` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/node.cpp#L182)):

- First it will call `_propagate_ready` on the children nodes, recursively.
- Then it calls `notification` with `NOTIFICATION_POST_ENTER_TREE`.
- Then it calls `notification` with `NOTIFICATION_READY`
- Finally it emits the ready signal.

Somewhere lost in there is when it calls `_ready`. We find that where `Node` handles the notification `NOTIFICATION_READY` ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/node.cpp#L125)).

When the `Node` gets `NOTIFICATION_READY`, it connects the handlers for `_input`, `_unhandled_input`, `_unhandled_key_input`, `_process`, and `_physics_process` (only if you declared them). Then it calls `_ready`. Will get back to that.

Thus, children nodes will get `NOTIFICATION_READY` first, and thus they will get their `_ready` called first.

---

### Ready and derived classes

But all of that is without talking about inheritance. *To be clear, I've been talking about children nodes in the scene tree, not derived classes.*

The script is, well, an instance of the class [`Script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_script.html). A `Node` *has a* `Script`. And there are different derived classes of `Script` for each language. We want [`GDScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html).

This is important, because, for example, if it were [`CSharpScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_csharpscript.html) it would use the inheritance mechanism of C#, and there you need to call `base._Ready`. *Of which there are examples, as pointed out by Vaillancourt.*

---

Let us look at the call of `_ready` again ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/main/node.cpp#L149)):

```
get_script_instance()->call_multilevel_reversed(SceneStringNames::get_singleton()->_ready, NULL, 0);
```

So, we get an instance of `Script` (of `GDScript` for our case), an we call `call_multilevel_reversed` on it.

This is how `call_multilevel_reversed` looks like ([source](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp)):

```
void GDScriptInstance::_ml_call_reversed(GDScript *sptr, const StringName &p_method, const Variant **p_args, int p_argcount) {

    if (sptr->_base)
        _ml_call_reversed(sptr->_base, p_method, p_args, p_argcount);

    Variant::CallError ce;

    Map<StringName, GDScriptFunction *>::Element *E = sptr->member_functions.find(p_method);
    if (E) {
        E->get()->call(this, p_args, p_argcount, ce);
    }
}

void GDScriptInstance::call_multilevel_reversed(const StringName &p_method, const Variant **p_args, int p_argcount) {

    if (script.ptr()) {
        _ml_call_reversed(script.ptr(), p_method, p_args, p_argcount);
    }
}
```

As you can see, calling it will result in calling it on the base class *first*, recursively.

And there is the behavior you observe: Godot calls `_ready` on the base class, and then `_ready` on the derived class.

---

What about `_foo`? It is not special, Godot does not call it, it is a regular virtual call.

---

### How to avoid the logic on the base _ready to run

The first answer is: Don't put it on ready.

You can do this:

**Actor.gd**

```
class_name Actor extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    __ready()

func __ready():
    print("I am an actor")
    _foo()
        
func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was an actor")
```

**Player.gd**

```
class_name Player extends Actor

func __ready():
    print("I am a player")

func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was a player")
```

Since `__ready` is not one of the functions that Godot calls, it gets overriden as expected, and only the one on the derived class runs.

Drawback: you need to remember to use `__ready`.

---

This is arguably a cleaner way:

**Actor.gd**

```
class_name Actor extends KinematicBody2D

func _ready():
    if !get_script().resource_path.ends_with("Actor.gd"):
        return

    print("I am an actor")
    _foo()

func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was an actor")
```

**Player.gd**

```
class_name Player extends Actor

func _ready():
    print("I am a player")

func _foo():
    print("I was thinking I was a player")
```

As you can see, this approach requires nothing special of the derived class.

Note: `get_script().resource_path` will not end in `"Actor.gd"` if it is a build-in script on a scene (It is a reasonable assumption that it isn't, since build-in script can't have class names). Also using `get_script().resource_path` will not work if the script is not loaded from a `resource_path` (e.g. it was created in runtime).

---

Thus, How to know if an overriden method calls its super method or not?

Well, given that we can call the method on the base class with the -let us call it- dot notation (e.g. `.method()`), checking if a method does it, would require source code analysis. However, if the question is how to know if an overriden method class its super method *by default*. Then the answer is that it does not. Instead there are some methods that Godot call differently.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in gdscript/godot, but here is what I presume:

`_ready` being a "core" function acts similarly as a constructor. Typically (at least with a language like c++), when a new object is created, the most-parent constructor is called first, to make sure that the object is constructed when the child classes' constructor is called. The child not yet being constructed, if the function `foo` is called in the parent's constructor, it's the parent class's `foo` that will be called.

Although we have similarities here, it's not exactly the same.

`_ready` being a utility function, it will be called in order of the most parent's to the most child by the framework, making sure that what's "initialized" in the parents is initialized for the children--just like a constructor. However, unlike it would be the case in a constructor, all the objects having already been created, the "most overridden" function `foo` will hide all those that have been defined its ancestors.

Taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/search?l=C%23&q=_ready&type=), there are multiple occurrences where a "child" `_Ready()` will call it's `base._Ready()` as the first thing it does, so it appears this is consistent with the theory.

---

*How to know if an overriden method calls its super method or not?*

It's probably safe to say that the "top ancestor" will have it's `_ready` function called first, down to the "most overridden" `_ready` function. This behaviour will likely be the same for `_init`, although I have not found anything relevant about it.

For the other cases, the normal "hiding" will be done, and you'll call the the "most overridden" `foo` function.