# Extra constructor call when using inheritance in Godot

Tags: godot, oop, initialization

I'm trying to design a character system for my game. Considering I'll need a player and non-player characters - and non-player characters will further come in many more forms, making use of inheritance sounds almost necessary.

Right now, I'm trying to make every instance hold a dictionary of context options and I need the dictionary to be modified with every level of inheritance. From the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#class-constructor) I learned that the constructor implicitly calls the parent constructor, and so does the `_ready()` function as noted [here](https://godotengine.org/qa/72532/extending-parents-_ready-function-called-after-overriding).

... but first I wanted to test it, so I set up following scenes (slightly simplified):

## New scene: Character

- Character (`Type: Character` - here I'm not sure why, should be just `KinematicBody`)

... with the attached script:

```
extends KinematicBody

class_name Character

func _init():
    print_debug(self.to_string(), " Character _init()")

func _ready():
    print_debug(self.to_string(), " Character _ready()")
```

## New inherited scene: Player

- Player (`Inherits: Character.tscn, Type: KinematicBody`)

... and detatched the `Character.gd` script and attached a new script:

```
extends Character

class_name Player

func _init():
    print_debug(self.to_string(), " Player _init()")

func _ready():
    print_debug(self.to_string(), " Player _ready()")
```

... and I instantiate one Player scene as a child scene in my main scene (through editor, not code).

---

For some reason, whenever I instantiate *Player*, Godot consistently prints this:

```
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:22:_init()
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:22:_init()
[KinematicBody:1422] Player _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/player/Player.gd:26:_init()
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _ready()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:30:_ready()
[KinematicBody:1422] Player _ready()
   At: res://scenes/characters/player/Player.gd:34:_ready()
```

However, when I instantiate only *Character* in its place, the output is as I'd expect:

```
[KinematicBody:1425] Character _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:22:_init()
[KinematicBody:1425] Character _ready()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:30:_ready()
```

Where is the extra `_init()` call coming from? Sounds like something that could make a lot of mess if I didn't notice this and blindly used it.

Also why does *Player* show as a `Type: KinematicBody` when hovering over it in the scene inspector and not like `Type: Player`, the same way *Character* shows as `Type: Character` - or why don't they *both* show up as `Type: KinematicBody`?

## Edit

Following @Vaillancourt's suggestion, I placed breakpoints at each of the `print_debug()` calls. Stepping through the code, the last 4 prints behave as expected - first there's the *Character* constructor, implicitly called from the *Player* constructor, then the body of the *Player* constructor itself. This is clear from the backtrace. Same for the `_ready()` calls. But before this, there's always one extra *Character* constructor call not called from the *Player* constructor.

Same goes when I put multiple *Player* instances into the scene. Both had the correct constructor calls preceded by one extra, separate call.

Putting a *Character* instance along with a *Player* instance to the scene resulted in a - once again - malfunctioning *Player* (three `_init()` and two `_ready()` calls) and a correctly functioning *Character* (just one `_init()` and one `_ready()` call).

Comment: Does godot allow you to put breakpoints in the code to see the stack trace when you get there?

Comment: @Vaillancourt There's definitely a way to place breakpoints, but I have little experience with debuggers (lived my whole life just logging everything), so I actually haven't thought of this. Thank you for the pointer! I'll look into it and see if I can get my answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated version of the initialization process ([old version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66947013/402022)):

**Node instancing**

1. If the `Node` is an scene instance, do **Scene instancing** for the corresponding scene, and take the root node. Otherwise, create a new `Node` instance.
2. Script Change. If the `Node` script is different to the one we want (either it didn't have because we just created a new node, or it has a different one set by scene instancing):

   1. Change the Script.
   2. If the script has *new* variables, allocate them. Initialize variables which are not `onready` to their default value if specified, zeroed otherwise.
   3. Send `script_changed` signal.
   4. Call `_init` on it. Base class `_init` runs first.
3. Set properties (initialize `export` variables, and any custom setters run if the value is not the default, even if the value is the same it has). *I think should consider "Script change" a property that is being set, but it is such an special case.*

**Scene instancing**

1. Do **Note instancing** for the notes, from the root to the leafs.
2. Connect IDE signals. Including connections from and to future children.
3. Parenting. From root to the leafs:

   1. Add the node to its parent.
   2. `NOTIFICATION_PARENTED` (18).
4. `NOTIFICATION_INSTANCED` (20). *On the root node.*
5. Current scene handing. If instancing the current scene:

   1. Add the root node as child to the `root` `Viewport`.
   2. `NOTIFICATION_PARENTED` (18). *On the root node.*
   3. Entering the scene tree. From root to leafs:

      1. `NOTIFICATION_ENTER_TREE` (10).
      2. Call `_enter_tree` on it. Base class `_enter_tree` runs first.
      3. Send `tree_entered` signal.
   4. Ready mechanism. From leafs to root:

      1. `NOTIFICATION_POST_ENTER_TREE` (27).
      2. Initialize any `onready` variables.
      3. Call `_ready` on it. Base class `_ready` runs first.
      4. `NOTIFICATION_READY` (13).
      5. Send `ready` signal.

---

You have a stored scene `Character.tscn` where you have a `KinematicBody` that has a script `Character.gd`.

And then, in another scene, you have an instance of that scene. And to that instance you set a script `Player.gd`.

So, when that scene instantiates, it loads and instances the other scene (`Character.tscn`), which has `Character.gd`. Then Godot runs `_init()` on it:

```
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:22:_init()
```

Then Godot sets the new script (`Player.gd`). And Godot runs `_init()` on it, which has to run `_init()` on the parent class first:

```
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:22:_init()
[KinematicBody:1422] Player _init()
   At: res://scenes/characters/player/Player.gd:26:_init()
```

And then Godot moves on to running `_ready`. Which runs on the parent class first:

```
[KinematicBody:1422] Character _ready()
   At: res://scenes/characters/Character.gd:30:_ready()
[KinematicBody:1422] Player _ready()
   At: res://scenes/characters/player/Player.gd:34:_ready()
```

---

You can confirm the change of script by printing `(self.get_script() as GDScript).resource_path`. With that added to your debug prints, this is how it looks like:

```
[KinematicBody:1201] Character _init() res://Main/Character.gd
   At: res://Main/Character.gd:6:_init()
[KinematicBody:1201] Character _init() res://Main/Player.gd
   At: res://Main/Character.gd:6:_init()
[KinematicBody:1201] Player _init() res://Main/Player.gd
   At: res://Main/Player.gd:6:_init()
[KinematicBody:1201] Character _ready() res://Main/Player.gd
   At: res://Main/Character.gd:9:_ready()
[KinematicBody:1201] Player _ready() res://Main/Player.gd
   At: res://Main/Player.gd:9:_ready()
```

---

You have the current scene, so Godot goes over **scene instancing** for it, which does **node instancing** on its nodes from root to leafs. Which encounters a node that is an instance of `Character.tscn`. So Godot goes over **scene instancing** for `Character.tscn`, which does **node instancing** on its nodes. There Godot sets the script `character.gd`. Since the script changed (from none to `character.gd`) Godot and calls `_init` on it. That is the first `_init` call.

After **scene instancing** for `Character.tscn` finished, **scene instancing** for the current scene continues. So it changes the script to `player.gd`. Since the script changed (from `character.gd` to `player.gd`) Godot calls `_init` on it, but first it calls `_init` on the base class. So you get two more `_init` calls.

Afterwards, since we are loading the current scene, it reaches the ready mechanism, where Godot calls `_ready`. Which are also two calls because Godot call `_ready` on the base class first.

---

A few extra notes:

- When the script changes, there is a `script_changed`. But if you connect to it from the current scene, you will not get it. This is because the IDE signals has not been connected yet at the time. However, the IDE signals for `Character.tscn` would have been connected for the second script change (from `character.gd` to `player.gd`).
- The values of the properties of the node are not lost when switching scripts.
- I don't think there is a way to know ahead of time if the script will be changed.

Comment: I had a chance to talk about this yesterday with a few people and was, among other things, forwarded this [issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/31002), which talks about this like it's a bug. From your explanation, it sounds like it's (albeit unfortunately) by design. That's why I'm even more confused to hear it should be fixed in the 3.4 release.

Comment: As a side-note for anyone else coming here, this mechanism ([multilevel callbacks](https://godotengine.org/qa/9244/can-override-the-_ready-and-_process-functions-child-classes)) is being entirely removed in the 4.0 release in favor of the explicit `super()` calls.

Comment: @MartyCagas It is a design, and not wrong per-se, but NOT the easier to understand and workaround. It wasn't well documented to begin with. There is not a place in the documentation that gives an overall picture of the process, just bits here and there, with gaps in between. I don't know if it is worth patching for 3.4. It makes sense to me it would be as a redesign like they did for Godot 4.0. I went over `_ready` in more detail in another answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/192257/10408) by the way.